# How to read lines from a file into a multidimensional array (or an array of lists) in python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a file with a format similar to this:

```
a,3,4,2,1
3,2,1,a,2
```

I want to read the file and create an array of lists

in a way that:

```
array[0] = ['a','3','4','2','1']
array[1] = ['3','2','1','a','2']
```

How can I do that?

So far I am stuck with:

```
f = open('./urls-eu.csv', 'r')
for line in f:
    arr = line.split(',')
print arr
```

I am really new to python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you're almost there, you just need to do:

```
arr = [line.split(',') for line in open('./urls-eu.csv')]
```

it iteratively process file line by line, splits each line by comma and accumulates resulting lists into a list of lists. you can drop opening mode (`'r'`) since it's a default one.

Answer (score 16):

Batteries included:

```
>>> import csv
>>> array = list( csv.reader( open( r'./urls-eu.csv' ) ) )
>>> array[0]
['a', '3', '4', '2', '1']
>>> array[1]
['3', '2', '1', 'a', '2']
```